# How to use contact module of Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, emails

I want to use drupal 7 core module for contact.
I want to use it as block so that I can add a contact form to the right sidebar of your website which should be shown at every page. or render it anywhere in the page
I saw this on drupal site and tried to use it.

```
<?php
print drupal_get_form('contact_mail_page');
?>
```

It is showing me this

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'contact_mail_page' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 841
```

So any suggestion how I can use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('contact_site_page')) {
  require_once drupal_get_path('module', 'contact').'/contact.pages.inc';
  $output = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
  print drupal_render($output);
}
?>
```

and put `print drupal_render($output);` where ever you want to put the contact form.

as another solution you can also assign a region for where you want the contact form to be then place the form in there.

Comment: This should work. Just once change to make is more bullet proof, `require_once` could be replaced by `module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');`

Comment: @AjitS there exists many ways,  just try them ;)

Comment: @Drupalist `module_load_include()` is the preferred method for including module files

Comment: thank you very much....
You guys are genius....
thank you @AjitS...
Please tell me about another solutions also how to do with region

Comment: @Clive yes you are right. there is something I was going to ask you about your website. I saw your slide called `deckslide`, what is it? a module or you built it?

Comment: @Drupalist That is a very old version of the (now Wordpress only) [SlideDeck widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slidedeck2/) that I bodged into a custom module about 4 years ago

Comment: @Clive I was going to build a module that slides `blocks` in that way, I just wanted to know if it already exists or not. tnx